# How to get a count of the word sizes in a large amount of text?

Tags: regex

I have a large amount text - roughly 7000 words.

I would like to get a count of the words sizes e.g. the count of 4 letter words, 6 letters words using regex.

I am unsure how to go about this - my thought process so far would be to split the sentence into a String array which would allow me to count each individual elements size. Is there an easier way to go about this using a regex? I am using Groovy for this task.

EDIT: So i did get this working using an normal array but it was slightly messy. The final solution simply used Groovy's countBy() method coupled with a small amount of logic for anyone who might come across a similar problem.

Comment: Regex isn't so good for counting.  But splitting the words into an array and then using the string length function sounds good to me.

Comment: I think it is just wasting memory. Regex doesn't count but matches. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget word boudary token `\b`. If you don't put it at both ends of a `\w{n}` token then all words longer than `n` characters are also found. For a 4 character word `\b\w{4}\b` for a six character long word use `\b\w{6}\b`. [Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/tI0lD0/1) with 7000 words as input string.

Java implementation:

```
String dummy = ".....";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w{6}\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dummy);

int count = 0;
while (matcher.find())
    count++;

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Thank you for the demo. So if i am not mistaken i could use the method in your demo with a loop that increments every time a word length matches the length specified?

Comment: In which language you are going to implement?

Comment: Groovy - similar to Java.

Comment: I'm not a Java guy but added some codes to demonstrate it. @Perfect_Comment

Comment: Thank you for taking to time to add that code - it's a great help and something i can definitely work with!

Answer (score 0):

Read the file using any stream word by word and calculate their length. Store counters in an array and increment values after reading each word.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate regexes for each size you want.

- `\w{6}` would get each word with 6 letters exactly
- `\w{7}` would get each word with 7 letters exactly
- and so on...

So you could run one of these regex on the text, with the global flag enabled (finding every instance in the whole string). This will give you an array of every match, which you can then find the length of.